# Do "Product Name" and "Bundle Display Name" have to match?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I've recently submitted an app to the app store. I didn't really understand everything about the "Product name" and the "Bundle Display Name" until now. I originally was calling my app "Knock Out", so the Product Name is "iKnockout3D." I later changed the name to "Shatter 3D," so the app that I have in review has an iTunes name and bundle display name of "Shatter 3D," but a product and executable name if "iKnockout3D." Is this something that could cause it to be rejected? I'm trying to decide if I should pull it now and resubmit or take the risk and wait...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Rebranding your app doesn't involve the bundle identifier which is rather handy.